# How to maintain Direction in SimpleITK image to numpy array conversion?

Tags: python, numpy, imaging, simpleitk, medical-imaging

I have three different isotropic MRI DICOM volumes of the same object, each with a different direction (orthogonal sagittal, coronal and transverse acquisitions of same object).

I would like to convert them to numpy arrays and plot them, in such a way that their indexing matches. Let's say that if I have three numpy arrays issued from sitk images:

```
sag_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage( sag_sitk )
dors_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage( dors_sitk )
trans_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage( trans_sitk )
```

I would like to be able to plot them using the same indexing, so that the slices

```
sag_array[:,:,index]
dors_array[:,:,index]
trans_array[:,:,index]
```

correspond to the same view, with no flipping or inversion of the axes.

I guess this info is contained in the Direction of the SimpleITK images, is there a way to transfer it to the numpy arrays after the conversion?

Does the Direction property in general have any effect on the numpy conversion, or is it lost?

Comment: Numpy arrays don't have any meta-information with them, so the direction is lost.  To get your volumes to match in numpy you're going to have to flip them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by pre-processing all the images with the `sitk.Resample()` function to a common Origin and Direction. In this way, when converting to numpy arrays, since they occupied the same physical space, they're sliced coherently among each other.